# How to pip install python packages when anaconda is installed?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I installed anaconda and now I can't use `pip` to install packages on my version 3.6 of python, instead it installs them on anaconda. If I type `pip -V` I get:

```
pip 9.0.1 from /anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

so how do I make it so that it shows:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/
```

instead?. 
Or am I missing something?

Comment: Just change your environment-variables (= path). By the way: anaconda-install explicitly asks you @install-time if it should write those paths and render your os-based pip unreachable (you did say: yes)! **Edit:** you can try ```pip3```. I don't know, but maybe it's still pointing to your os-based pip.

Comment: Didn't realize I would need it at the time. Any idea how to reverse it? All I see on my `.bash_profile` is `export PATH="/anaconda/bin:$PATH"` . What exactly do I have to change?

Comment: Remove the whole line (and restart or re-login or re-load bash env). I'm not exactly sure, where in your OS the system-pip is prepared, but removing this line makes the anaconda one not found automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Well, anaconda comes with its own python directory, which replaces your default python and thus renders its `pip` useless.
You need to edit `.bashrc` (or `.zshrc` in case you are using zsh). There you need to change the path to your original python directory. First of all delete anaconda related `export PATH` and put in:

`export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:$PATH"`

If you are using Debian based system. You can also try `update-alternatives`. This is very powerful (yet easy to use) tool, which allows you to change current default python version without manually updating `.bashrc`.
How to use `update-alternatives` can be found here: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux#h2-change-python-version-system-wide

Answer (score 0):

I had to work this out myself awhile back:

On Windows 10, I entered command prompt (ie`cmd`) and used:

```
python -m pip install --target=C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\
```

modulename
I assume if you can find the folder your python 3.6 then you'll be able to use:

```
python -m pop install --target=whereever\your\python\is themoduleyouwant
```

Note that the space between the path and the module name is necessary.